# Using javascript on a wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

This is my code. Is this the proper way of including javascript on a wordpress page? Im just a newbee. I think this question is answered but I dont understand it. Thanks for the help stackoverflowers!!!

```
<html><head><title></title>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

var numQues = 5;
var numChoi = 3;

var answers = new Array(5);
answers[0] = "2";
answers[1] = "14";
answers[2] = "7";
answers[3] = "6";
answers[4] = "2";

function getScore(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;

  for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i*numChoi;
    for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";

  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
  }
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;

}

// -->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="quiz">
1. X + 6 = 8
What is the value of x?
<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="3">3<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="2">2<br>
<p>

2. x - 10 = 4
What is the value of x?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="14">14<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="13">13<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="15">15<br>
<p>

3. -4 = x + 3
What is the value of x?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="5">5<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="6">6<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="7">7<br>
<p>

4. 4x - 3 = 3 + 2x + 6
What is the value of x?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="8">8<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="6">6<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="4">4<br>
<p>

5. 3x - 3 + 2x = x + 5 
What is the value of x?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="4">4<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="2">2<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="6">6<br>
<p>

<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear"><p>
Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage"><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>

</body></html>
```

Comment: lgtm... Is there an error? Otherwise this isn't really a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to include a javascript file that's in your Theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/pathto/yourscript.js"></script>
```

Here's how to add "inline" script on a template :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* javascript goes here */
</script>
```

Both can go either in the `head` or above the closing `body` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Very nice to include JavaScript to your theme through functions.php with `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_scripts' );`

The example function for your functions.php to add JavaScript:

```
function your_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'myslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.myslider.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true ); 

    if ( is_home() ) { 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'home-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home-script.js', array( 'jquery' ),'', true );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_scripts' );
```

You will find here a parameter `array( 'jquery' )`, which means, that this script requires jQuery to run. So it goes **after** jQuery is loaded.

The advantages of this method are:

- You can make conditions and avoid loading of certain scripts on pages/posts/archives, which don't use it.
- By this method the jQuery library is loaded only once. It goes with WordPress core.
- If you require different version of jQuery you are able to unregister this version, and register the new one with `wp_deregister_script( $handle );`